# how to change fragment without TimerTask stopping. Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, timer, timertask

I have a problem with changing `Fragments`. 
In my app I use `TimerTisk` for updating `TextView` every second (timer for user), when we change `Fragment` we have `NullPointerException`. I know why this is happening but I can't stop  `TimerTask` because my timer for user should working until user stop it himself. How can I solve this problem how timer could work in the backgroud?
My `Fragment` :

```
public class WalkingFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String timeTxt = "";
    TextView textViewWalkingTimer;
    Button startWalkingBC;

    private Timer walkingTimer;
    private int period = 0;
    private boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_walking, container, false);

        textViewWalkingTimer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewWalkingTimer);

        startWalkingBC = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start_walking);
        startWalkingBC.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public void startWalkingButtonClick() {

        if (!flag) {
            walkingTimer = new Timer();
            walkingTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TimerForWalking();
                }
            }, 0, 1000);

            startWalkingBC.setText("Stop");
            flag = true;
        } else if (flag) {
            period = 0;
            if (walkingTimer != null) {
                walkingTimer.cancel();
                flag = false;
                textViewWalkingTimer.setText("");
                startWalkingBC.setText("Start");
            }
        }
    }

    private void TimerForWalking() {
        this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            period++;
            timeTxt = (new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss")).format(new Date(period * 1000));
            textViewWalkingTimer.setText(timeTxt);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.start_walking:
                startWalkingButtonClick();
                break;

        .................

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine, until we change `Fragment`. I new in `Android` and this my first app. Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The Fragments you create are going to keep alive until the parent `Activity` is alive too. I recommend you communicate the fragment where you start the timer with the Activity to store its value and retrieve it in another fragment.
Also I recommend you check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to check how to communicate them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will try.